# Was John von Neumann able to recall from memory every book he had ever read?

Tags: intelligence, cognitive-science

From Wikipedia's article on [Eidetic memory's prevalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory#Prevalence)

> According to [Herman Goldstine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Goldstine), the mathematician [John von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann) was able to recall from memory every book he had ever read. [[15]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory#cite_note-15)

Refering to Page 167 of Goldstine's [The Computer from Pascal to von Neumann](https://books.google.com/books?id=jCSpiVBH5W0C&pg=PA167)

> As far as I could tell, von Neumann was able on once reading a book or article to quote it back verbatim; moreover he could do it years later without hesitation.

He then goes on with a story about him challenging von Neumann to tell how a particular book's first chapter started with and JVN being able to recite it flawlessly.

The same section of the Wikipedia article starts with the following sentence

> Eidetic memory is typically found only in young children, as it is virtually nonexistent in adults

Now , *extraordinary* does little favor in describing von Neumann's mental capabilities and scientific contributions but I think Goldstine's claims are bold even for someone like him. There are [many more anecdotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann#Cognitive_abilities) about his abilities and, indeed, there are people who have savant skills, however even the ones who have had those skills "over-developed" performed significantly below average in other cognitive tasks. That makes the story about Von Neumann even less plausible, considering he was a polymath.

Finding a source disputing Goldstine's claims about von Neumann is obviously not the answer one should be looking for however it would be interesting to discuss, from a neuroscientific point of view, if it's really probable that the human brain can store such large amounts of information.

Comment: if you want a discussion, psychology and neuroscience SE would be a better place. Are you asking here if JvN never forgot anything? There is a book which makes that even stronger claim https://books.google.com/books?id=_GpQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA104

Comment: An no, "eidetic memory" is not the same as remembering any text read. The latter is a feat that was claimed by others e.g. " Kim Peek *, the 53-year-old savant who was the basis for Dustin Hoffman’s character in Rain Man, is said to have memorized every page of the 9,000-plus books he has read at 8 to 12 seconds per page (each eye reads its own page independently), though that claim has never been rigorously tested." 9000 books easily fit on a DVD.

Comment: He also wrote six operas in two years, and learnt to walk when he was only 3 weeks old.

Comment: Goldstine and von Neumann worked together for many years; first during WWII and then at the Institute for Advanced Study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Goldstine